# Neo4j: Trying to find strings that follow a specific word or pattern in different blocks of data but can't figure out the right query to achieve that

Tags: string, neo4j, substring

I'm trying to find the values of a particular attribute contained inside the data of a particular type of node in our database. I think what I need in order to do that is to match for a certain string that always precedes these values, and then extract those values from the block of data.

So, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
MATCH 
    (c:course)-[:PARENT_OF*]->(n:item) 
WHERE 
    n.data CONTAINS "some string"       
RETURN 
    {the text immediately following "some string"}
```

Sorry for being a little vague... Not sure I can be specific for various reasons.

Basically, I want to find – say if the block of data is 'Hello my name is Sally and I really could go for some fries right now' – the name in the block of data, so, Sally. Additionally, if there's still another name in the data, that follows the pattern "my name is ___", I want to find that too. Does that make sense?

Is that possible to do in Neo4j?

I know there's a way to return the entire contents of/data contained in a node, and I also now know that there is a way to return a portion of the contents in that node, but that's where I get stuck, because I can only get - from the above sparse example, let's say - Neo4j to return only some substring of the string I provided, not anything following it.

I've tried

```
...
RETURN 
    substring(n.data,100,500)
```

to find a portion of the data, starting at the 100th character in the data, and stopping at the 500th character.

I also have tried

```
...
RETURN 
    right('hello', 3)
```

to find a portion of the substring in quotes ('hello'), and specifically starting after the 3rd character in that substring (so that I'd get a result like 'llo').

I guess I don't know how to query a pattern in Neo4j such that it can give me what follows that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Håkan's answer a bit. If you say that there may be more than one name in the same string, e.g. "Hello my name is John and my sisters name is Jane and we both likes fries", and you want to extract all names that follows the key "name is " then this might do the trick

```
WITH "name is " AS key 
MATCH (n:item) WHERE n.data CONTAINS key 
WITH key, n.data AS text, apoc.text.indexesOf(n.data, key) AS indexes 
UNWIND indexes AS index 
WITH key, text, index+size(key) AS nameindex 
RETURN substring(text, nameindex, apoc.text.indexOf(text, " ", nameindex)-nameindex)
```

One caveat is that this version doesn't work if there is a name at the end of the text (since it requires a space to follow the names). Need to think a bit more on how to solve that case as well.

Edit:

Here is a version that solves that special case as well (a name appears at the end of the string, without a subsequent space):

```
WITH "name is " AS key 
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.data CONTAINS key 
WITH key, n.data AS text, apoc.text.indexesOf(n.data, key) AS indexes 
UNWIND indexes AS index 
WITH key, text, index+size(key) AS nameindex, apoc.text.indexOf(text, " ", index+size(key)) AS endindex
RETURN
CASE endindex
WHEN -1 THEN substring(text, nameindex)
ELSE substring(text, nameindex, endindex-nameindex)
END
```

By the way, this requires that you have the "APOC Core" library installed (it is installed by default on Aura, but if you run your own instance you need to install it. This is simply done by moving the file apoc-5.X.X-core.jar from the labs folder to the plugins folder and then restarting).

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the core APOC function [apoc.text.regexGroups](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.text/apoc.text.regexGroups/) to use a regular expression that searches case-insensitively and ignores non-alphanumeric characters surrounding the name. For example:

```
UNWIND [
    "Hello my name is Sally and I really could go for some fries right now. Did I mention that my name is Sally?",
    "My name is Waldo but sometimes I say my name is Charlie, and sometimes I say my name is **Fido**. Arf!"
] AS s

UNWIND apoc.text.regexGroups(s, '(?i)my name is \W*(\w+)') AS group
RETURN s, apoc.coll.flatten(COLLECT(TAIL(group))) AS names
```

returns:

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════════╤════════════════════════════╕
│s                                      │names                       │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════╪════════════════════════════╡
│"Hello my name is Sally and I really co│["Sally", "Sally"]          │
│uld go for some fries right now. Did I │                            │
│mention that my name is Sally?"        │                            │
├───────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│"My name is Waldo but sometimes I say m│["Waldo", "Charlie", "Fido"]│
│y name is Charlie, and sometimes I say │                            │
│my name is **Fido**. Arf!"             │                            │
└───────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: I agree. I've found ChatGPT is pretty good at suggesting the regex if you frame the question well and give an example. If you're not a regex ninja, I'd suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the text to start with your text fragment you could do like this:

```
UNWIND [
    "Hello my name is Sally and I really could go for some fries right now",
    "Hello my name is Ben and I really could go for a burger right now"
] AS text
WITH text, "Hello my name is" as q
WHERE text starts with q
RETURN trim(right(text, size(text)-size(q)))
```

If instead you only expect the text to contain the text fragment, you need to use apoc.text.indexOf:

```
UNWIND [
    "Hello my name is Sally and I really could go for some fries right now",
    "Hello my name is Ben and I really could go for a burger right now"
] AS text
WITH text, "my name is" as q
WHERE text contains q
RETURN trim(right(text, size(text)-apoc.text.indexOf(text,q)-size(q)))
```